# Equation with log and power in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, expression

I am trying to calculate total suspended solids using Sentinel 2 in GEE with this equation

```
TSS = 172.191 * log(pow(2) (Green/Red))) − (190.809 * log(Green/Red)) + 61.6
```

I write this code and it doesn't work:

```js
var TSS_expression = Burullus_summer.expression(
    '172.191 * log(Green/Red)) − 190.809 * (log(Green/Red)) + 61.6', {  
    'Green': Burullus_summer.select('B3'), // Select band 3 (green) from the S2 filtered image collection
    'Red': Burullus_summer.select('B4')  // Select band 4 (red) from the S2 filtered image collection
}).rename('TSS_br');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work' ? Do you get any error message or something else? Kindly specify.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is produced because you probably **copy/paste** the formula from the text on the paper and the character "−" is different from this "-" (true minus sign in Java Script language). On the other hand, your formula at **TSS_expression** is wrong. By searching in Internet, from [this reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7730694/), the correct expression is as follows:

[image]

So, your code can be rewritten (for Burullus area) as:

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(30.8444, 31.471);

Map.centerObject(pt, 10);

/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(pt))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

print(dataset);

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');

//TSS=172.191*log(Green/Red)**2 - 190.809*log(Green/Red) + 61.6

var TSS_expression = dataset.first().expression(
    '172.191*log(Green/Red)**2 - 190.809 * log(Green/Red) + 61.6', {  
    'Green': dataset.first().select('B3'), // Select band 3 (green) from the S2 filtered image collection
    'Red': dataset.first().select('B4')  // Select band 4 (red) from the S2 filtered image collection
}).rename('TSS_br'); 

print(TSS_expression);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["TSS_br"],
                     "min":8.74,
                     "max":128.14,
                     "palette":["14ffd5","0e36ff","22ff20","fff808","ffa908","ff3202"]};

Map.addLayer(TSS_expression, imageVisParam, 'TSS_expression');
```

After, running it at GEE code editor, the first image of TSS calculation ('2020-01-07') is added as follows:

[image]

Comment: It works. Thank you for your effort

Comment: So, I would appreciate that you mark as accepted this answer.